# Removing activity items from UIActivityViewController after choose WhatsApp

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivitycontroller

I am implementing `UIActivityViewController` to share text and image through other apps. My problem starts when WhatsApp doesn't accept text and image together, so I want to remove text (if exists) when user chooses to share with WhatsApp.

How can I remove some activity items after the destination app was choosen in `UIActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a class that conforms to `UIActivityItemSource`, and use it instead of passing the text or image directly to `UIActivityViewController`.

So instead of

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, text])
```

We would pass the new item sources

```
UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [ImageItemSource(image), TextItemSource(text)]
```

The item source classes will look something like this:

```swift
class TextItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    private let text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        super.init()
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        text
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        text
    }
}

class ImageItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    private let image: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.image = image
        super.init()
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        image
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        image
    }
}
```

Now that we have control over what we'll share, we can choose what *exactly* we share with each app by checking `activityType` before returning the data, and if we think we should not send anything at all, we can simply return `nil`.

In your case, if you want to share the text item with all apps except WhatsApp, you can simply do this:

```swift
class TextItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    ...
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        if activityType?.rawValue.starts(with: "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.") == true {
            // We'll return `nil` to WhatsApp forcing it to 
            //   ignore this whole text item and only show the image item instead
            return nil
        }

        return text
    }
    ...
}
```